# Aggregation in ForEach in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to aggregate the responses of each iteration of For Each. In each iteration I am getting Json data and I want to aggregate that Json data into Json Array/List. Please let me know how I can do that by using data weave in Transform or by any other way?

Below is sample Json data that I am getting in each iteration of For Each.

```
1st iteration:
{
    "accountId": "12345",
    "accountNumber": "999",
    "accountTitle": "ABC"
}

2nd iteration:
{
    "accountId": "98765",
    "accountNumber": "888",
    "accountTitle": "XYZ"
}

I want final aggregated output as below.  
{
  accountList: [
    {
        "accountId": "12345",
        "accountNumber": "999",
        "accountTitle": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "accountId": "98765",
        "accountNumber": "888",
        "accountTitle": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you accumulate values within a ForEach loop in Mule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027993/how-do-you-accumulate-values-within-a-foreach-loop-in-mule)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow something like

```
<!-- Define blank arraylist for aggregation -->
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-variable variableName="result"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[]]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <!-- generate response using flow logic and add following step for updating result array -->
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
                <dw:set-variable variableName="result"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.result ++ [payload]]]></dw:set-variable>
            </dw:transform-message>
        </foreach>
        <!-- Transform aggregated result to any format. I used JSON -->
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
accountList : flowVars.result]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

I have used Mule 3.x syntax. For mule 4 you can use `attribute` instead of `variable` for storing records. Dataweave syntax will remain same except for changing Dataweave language version from `1.0` to `2.0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In Mule 4 you should use variables (vars.x), not attributes.